# Windows 8 Apps Won't Open

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-apps

I recently found I was unable to open any modernui app.  They flash open and close instantly.  I have tried a myriad of things to fix it.

- Ran App Troubleshooter
- Removed anti-virus
- Checked permissions on folders
- Checked permissions on registry
- Updated all drivers that had updates

I ran process explorer and isolated the Windows Store app but I don't understand the output

I uploaded [winstore.pml](http://db.tt/fDjFqKC5) to my public dropbox.  Please help if you can, thanks.

Comment: have you tried `sfc /scannow`?

Comment: You need to make sure your not running as the built-in `Administrator` account and you have UAC enabled.

Comment: You can also uninstall any software specifically not designed to supported Windows 8.  Sounds like you have the same problem this user had.

Comment: I did sfc /scannow and I'm not on the built-in Administrator.  I also created a new user with a local account and it had the same problem.

Comment: So I guess this is a problem that cannot be solved?